# Как переопределить функцию render в React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, requirejs

```
define('chart', ['l/graph'], function (Graph) {
    ...
    return React.createClass({
        displayName: 'Chart',

        render: function() {
            ...
        }
    });
});
```

Данный код создаёт React компонент `Chart`. Подскажите как можно было бы переопределить метод `render` этого компонента при помощи JS?

P.S.: В JS не разбираюсь, прошу помочь.

Comment: Ну и старенькую же Вы версию реакта выбрали, конечно...

Comment: Да. React (with addons) v0.12.1

Comment: переопределить где? и для чего?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предположим, что имеется такой класс:

```
const Chart = React.createClass({
  displayName: 'Chart',

  render: function() {
    return (<div>Old render!</div>);
  }
});
```

Можно подменить функцию рендеринга через прототипирование, вот так:

```
Chart.type.prototype.render = function() {
  return <div>New render!</div>;
};
```

Пытаться подменить метод рендеринга для компонента считается злым хаком и не считается бэст практис. Полный пример кода:

```
import React from "react";

const Chart = React.createClass({
  displayName: "Chart",

  render: function() {
    return <div>Old render!</div>;
  }
});

Chart.type.prototype.render = function() {
  return <div>New render!</div>;
};

React.render(<Chart />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

В результате будет выведено:

> New render!

Создание компонентов через `createClass` считается устаревшим подходом. Советую смотреть в сторону новой версии `React`.

Comment: А возможно подменить какой либо другой метод? Подмена объекта перед созданием экземпляра не подходит. У меня есть сайт, менять код скриптов которого я не должен. Задача использовать для решения выполнение JS на странице.

Comment: @D.Stark простите, я в прототипизации немного не туда ходил, обновил ответ, подмена `render` метода возможна. Посмотрите обновленную версию.

Comment: Замечательно...